# Creating anagrams for a test DB

Tags: vb.net, anagram

I have a SQL Server DB containing real data (e.g. Customer names, ecc).
I'd like to transform it to a DB to show in presentations without showing the real names contained in there.

One solution could be to transform real names in anagrams (e.g.: a customer with name "abcdefg" could become "cfadgbe") so that original name is not too easily recognizable.

If you did something similar in the past (possibly in VB.NET, but C# is ok too), I'd really appreciate not to write from scratch such a procedure.

(If you did something different with the same goal... then it will be OK too!)

Comment: You might want to look up Shuffle Algorithm instead of anagrams. ex: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by creating random combinations of first names and last names that I collected in a separate table for this purpose. I also applied this technique to addresses (street, city) and generated random phone numbers. These fake addresses look like real addresses.

```
Dim firstNames = New List(Of String)
Dim lastNames = New List(Of String)

'TODO: Fill these lists with names

Dim random = New Random()
Dim numberOfAddresses = 100
For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfAddresses - 1
    Dim f = random.Next(firstNames.Count)
    Dim l = random.Next(lastNames.Count)
    Dim name = firstNames(f) & " " & lastNames(l)
    'TODO: update this name in the db
Next
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but nice code to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Why using anagrams? why not just creating random names? You could write a short process to hold a listo of say 100 first names and 100 last names and update your records with a random mix if both, wich will allow for you to have "understandable" names for customesr in stead of unreadable letter mixture...

Comment: Anagrams would be easier for me to remember the true customer names. But your suggestion is good and I could elaborate somthing appropriate for me from it.